# How to avoid casting arguments in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I want to get a List from repository and assert its contents.

In following code I get a warning that states that `Object` cannot be assigned to `List`

Is there any way to add better argument to handle such case?

```
myDomainObjectRepository.save(_) >> { arguments ->
   final List<MyDomainObject> myDomainObjects = arguments[0]
   assert myDomainObjects == [new MyDomainObject(someId, someData)]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Opals answer: There are two parts and a footnote in the [docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) that are relevant here:

> If the closure declares a single untyped parameter, it gets passed the
>   method’s argument list:

And

> In most cases it would be more convenient to have direct access to the
>   method’s arguments. If the closure declares more than one parameter or
>   a single typed parameter, method arguments will be mapped one-by-one
>   to closure parameters[footnote]:

Footnote:

> The destructuring semantics for closure arguments come straight from
>   Groovy.

The problem is that you have a single argument List, and since generics are erased groovy can't decide that you actually want to unwrap the list.

So a single non-`List` argument works fine:

```
myDomainObjectRepository.save(_) >> { MyDomainObject myDomainObject ->
   assert myDomainObject == new MyDomainObject(someId, someData)
}
```

or a `List` argument combined with a second, e.g., `save(List domain, boolean flush)`

```
myDomainObjectRepository.save(_, _) >> { List<MyDomainObject> myDomainObjects, boolean flush -> 
   assert myDomainObjects == [new MyDomainObject(someId, someData)]
}
```

So the docs are a little bit misleading about this edge case. I'm afraid that you are stuck with casting for this case.

---

Edit: You should be able to get rid of the IDE warnings if you do this.

```
myDomainObjectRepository.save(_) >> { List<List<MyDomainObject>> arguments ->
   List<MyDomainObject> myDomainObjects = arguments[0]
   assert myDomainObjects == [new MyDomainObject(someId, someData)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values) seems to be precise:

If the closure declares a single untyped parameter, it gets passed the method’s argument list

However I've just changed my spec that uses `rightShift` + `arguments` to accept a single type argument and it did work. Try it out.

Comment: my code works but IDE raises a warning - I would like to change it a way that it does not

Comment: @pixel what warning does it raise?

Comment: `Cannot assign 'Object' to 'List<MyDomainObject>` and another that `getAt` can't be applied to Integer

Comment: So it won't work without warnings. You can always utilize `SuppressWarnings`.