# How to make a List of Strings in Groovy

Tags: string, list, groovy, spock

I'm a bit puzzled by what's happening here. I'm trying to make a test which tests that `addLDocument()` is passed a `List` of `String`s where there are 10 `String`s in the `List`.  There are multiple calls to `addLDocument`... they should usually have 10 `String`s in the `List` passed as the parameter.

Clearly the test should currently be **failing** (it is, but in the wrong way), as I am currently only passing one `String` at a time. The aim is to change the code to make the test pass by packaging the succeeding `String`s up into batches of 10.

```
for( String textLine : allTextLines ) {
            List<String> textLines = []
            textLines.add( textLine )
            addLDocument( textLines )
}

def addLDocument( List<String> textLines ) {
        ...
}
```

In my test I have this:

```
    given:
    List stringVal

    ...

    then:
    1 * spyCH.addLDocument( _ ) >> { 
        arguments -> stringVal = arguments[ 0 ] 

    }
    println "stringVal $stringVal size ${stringVal.size()}"
    stringVal.size() == 10

    then:
    ( 1 .. _ ) * spyCH.addLDocument( _ ) >> null
```

... unfortunately I find, whatever I do, that `stringVal.size()` is counting the total number of ***characters*** in whatever `String`s are contained in `textLines`.

Why might that be?  How can I force `textLines` to contain a set of differentiated `String`s, and for `size()` to give the number of such elements in the `List`?

***later***

Oh dear, puzzling inconsistency now: after adding the lines suggested by daggett I then tried "rolling back": what did I have to do to get back to the "wrong" character-count, instead of element-count.  Replacing `List<String> xxx....` by `List xxx...` and then by `def xxx...` is now giving `size() == 1`.  [Weeps]

Comment: the loop `for` has a variable `textLines` declared inside of the loop that forces it to be re-declared in each next cycle...

Comment: As I already said to Leonard: I do not see what you describe happening. I just cannot reproduce it. If you can, please tell me which Spock and Groovy version you used and provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a full test and a full class under test.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801418/2145769 you are running into the same problem.

Comment: Actually I did not see any such behaviour when copying & pasting the code and making it runnable with a sample class. For me it was always 1-element lists and after fixing the code according to the OP's plan the test ran just fine without any casting or type definition.